# The start and end time is not being shown when I run the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am having some trouble populating the tables when running the code online. Appointment date that I created in the DbInitializer appears but the StartTime and EndTime aren't showing online.

I think it has something to do with my appointments controller. If anyone can help that would be much appreciated.

This is the index part of the AppointmentController

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        var appointments = from s in _context.Appointments.Include(a => a.Customer).Include(a => a.Staff)

                           select s;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {

            case "Date":
                appointments = appointments.OrderBy(s => s.AppointmentDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                appointments = appointments.OrderByDescending(s => s.AppointmentDate);
                break;
            default:
                appointments = appointments.OrderBy(s => s.AppointmentDate);
                break;

        }

        return View(await appointments.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

This is the model for the Appointments

```
{
 public class Appointment
{

    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int StaffID { get; set; }


    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    //[Display(Name = "Appointment Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Appointment Date")]
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }

   [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{00:00:00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{00:00:00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }


    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Staff Staff { get; set; }
}
}


                           select s;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {

            case "Date":
                appointments = appointments.OrderBy(s => s.AppointmentDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                appointments = appointments.OrderByDescending(s => s.AppointmentDate);
                break;
            default:
                appointments = appointments.OrderBy(s => s.AppointmentDate);
                break;

        }

        return View(await appointments.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

**UPDATE**
This is the code that is in my DbInitializer

```
        var appointments = new Appointment[]
        {
        new Appointment{CustomerID=1,StaffID=1,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/07/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("16:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")},
        new Appointment{CustomerID=2,StaffID=2,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/05/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")},
        new Appointment{CustomerID=3,StaffID=3,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/04/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")},
        new Appointment{CustomerID=4,StaffID=4,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/03/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")},
        new Appointment{CustomerID=5,StaffID=5,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/02/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")},
        new Appointment{CustomerID=6,StaffID=6,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/09/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")},
        new Appointment{CustomerID=7,StaffID=7,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/08/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")},
        new Appointment{CustomerID=8,StaffID=8,AppointmentDate=DateTime.Parse("20/06/2017"),StartTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00"),EndTime=DateTime.Parse("17:00:00")}

        };
        foreach (Appointment c in appointments)
        {
            context.Appointments.Add(c);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is a screen shot of the appointments part. I have populated the database to show a start and end time but as you can see nothing is being pulled through.

[image]

Comment: maybe the issue is in the UI binding part?

Comment: First put your result in temp list variable. Watch result of your query. Does items have this columns with expected values?. If true the problem is in mvc formating data. If false use SQL profiler to see EF query excited against database (does EF select query contains expected columns)

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with my mvc formatting as I can view all the data in the SQL explorer. When I go to create a new appointment the appointment date works but the start and end time still don't pass the values I give them. What could be the problem with this? I have looked at the UI binding and it all seems correct to me.